# How to use LIKE query in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

LIKE query in mysql, queries the database and disregards case. 
For example:

```
"bzupnick" = "Bzupnick" #  false
"bzupnick" LIKE "Bzupnick" # true
```

So how does one do a LIKE query in Ruby on Rails.

Here's an example query:

```
@results = User.joins(:jobs).where(:jobs => { :job_name => job }, :users => { :zip => zip })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this..

```
User.joins(:job).where("job_name like ? and name like ?","%Dummy%", "%Bzupnick")
```

You can also verfify the SQL query by putting to_sql at the end of the above statement

Comment: So the "?"s and "%" thing didn't work, but using interpolation, it worked beautifully.